# Can I send an object via TCP using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, tcp, client-server, distributed

I'm trying to send and "message" object via TCP on Ruby and my client class simply don't see any thing comming. What am I doing wrong?

My message class (that I'm trying to send)

```
class Message

  attr_reader :host_type, :command, :params  
  attr_accessor :host_type, :command, :params

  def initialize(host_type, command, params)
    @host_type = host_type
    @command = command
    @params = params
  end
end
```

My "Server" class

```
require 'socket' 
require_relative 'message'               


class TCP_connection 

  def start_listening
    puts "listening"
    socket = TCPServer.open(2000) 
    loop {                          
      Thread.start(socket.accept) do |message|
        puts message.command
      end
    }
  end

  def send_message
    hostname = 'localhost'
    port = 2000

    s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

    message = Message.new("PARAM A", "PARAM B", "PARAM C")

    s.print(message)

    s.close 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below an example of client server comunication via json. You will expect something like this `RuntimeError: {"method1"=>"param1"}`. Instead of raising errors, process this json with the server logic.

**Server**

```
require 'socket'
require 'json'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop {
  client = server.accept
  params = JSON.parse(client.gets)
  raise params.inspect
}
```

**Client**

```
require 'socket'
require 'json'

host = 'localhost'
port = 2000

s = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

request = { 'method1' => 'param1' }.to_json
s.print(request)

s.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize your object. The most portable way to do this is using YAML. First, require the `yaml` library:

```
require "yaml"
```

Than, replace `s.print(message)` with `s.print(YAML.dump(message))`.